# Reuse layout through Windows Phone 8 app - Any Masterpage equivalent for WP8?

Tags: layout, windows-phone-8, reusability

I have a layout which I wanted to reuse through out my WP8 app. Is it possible without having to copy and past it in each screen?

Is there any kind of "masterpage" (used for reusing layouts in other .Net project types)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no masterpage equivalent on Windows Phone, but you can easily create something similar. Create a `UserControl` find bindable "body" part and use it on every page.

Take a look at http://gregit.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/master-pages-for-windows-phone/ for inspiration

Comment: Magellan doesn't work for Windows Phone projects =(
How could I create a "bindable body" on Windows Phone projects? I understand this technique as I've used it in another type of projects but I don't know what is equivalent on WP8

Comment: have you tried the WP8 version the author created https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqapp3ctsh5obe2/Magellan.Layout.WP8.dll ?

Comment: Yes. I found out why it wasn't working. Now I'm trying to do exactly how he does in the printscreens and it can deploy with no problem since I don't set the "Source" attribute of the "Layout" control. When I set Source="/myProjectName;component/Master/myLayoutFile.xaml", I  start to get the exception on the InitializeComponent() method saying "Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassCanOnlyBeUsedOnLoadComponent'. [Line: 2 Position: 13]"

Do you have any clue what it might mean?

Comment: Oh, apparently I can't have a .cs file associated with my layout file. I removed it and it's now deploying (even though not showing the contents I put on the ZonePlaceHolder controls in my MainPage).. but, well.. if I can't have a .cs file associated with my layout file, I'll need another solution than Magellan because I need some logic there =/

Comment: If you use MVVM, you do not need a .cs file with logic. Just use binding and bind to properties / methods in some base ViewModel